# How to maintain gridview values in session before postback

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have `Gridview` in design

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridBudgetRelease" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false"
        ShowFooter="True" CssClass="substitutes">
 </asp:GridView>
```

In code behind I am assigning `Gridview` values to one `Session` variable

```
SessionWrapper.GridViewInfo = gridBudgetRelease;
```

I am adding one row to the Gridview through datatable (public DataTable table { get; set; })

```
 gridBudgetRelease.DataSource = table;
 gridBudgetRelease.DataBind();
```

I am not getting why session `Gridview` row count also updated..?

Answer (score 0):

It's updated cause it's a pointer to the same object you change.

Try to save data source somewhere instead.

Comment: I want save in session because I want to retrieve old data(What are the values before postback)